# PHP Code Not Pulling Sql Table

Tags: php

I am having a problem with my php code, it is not pulling my table row from mysql database. Does this code look correct.

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="marquee"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

    <?php
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
test
<? echo $rows['scroll']; 
   echo $rows['id'];
?>
```

Comment: looks fine what error do you get? if no errors please do var_dump($rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this, and try again.

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="marquee"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "$rows[scroll] $rows[id]";} ?>
```

**For updating row through html form**

Below, is the code to update but, you must post `$new_value` and `$id` first so, sql know which one to update.

`$result = mysql_query("UPDATE marquee SET scroll='$new_value' WHERE id='$id'") 
or die(mysql_error());`

For the above code, you should use html form to send values like:

```
<form method="" post="">
<input type="text" name="new_value" />
<input type="text" name="id" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

The above to code + the passing of variables are all you need to update that table

Comment: I just spotted un-closed bracket, try again.

Comment: ok got it..awesome this works. can i use a html form...a input field and submit button to update my single sql row?

Comment: i want to update the scroll row, i will be using this code in a marquee scroll

Comment: <?php 
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE marquee SET scroll='$new_value' WHERE scroll='$scroll'") or die(mysql_error());

echo '
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="new_value" />
<input type="text" name="scroll" /><input name="Submit" type="Submit" />
</form> '; ?>

Comment: Because, I left some things for you to include, and you just used the code as is without adding anything to it. Just give me 5 minutes, I will send you the codes

Comment: the post so this means ill need to add the method ="post"

Comment: No, not post only. What about the action=""? the action means the page where this form to be POSTED? index.php or update.php... I will work with update and give you the script

Comment: what is the id number of the srcoll column?

Comment: this form will be on the administrator control panel for the backend

Comment: check my new answer. id for srcoll must be 1 and all you have to do is enter in the form with the word you want to update it, and submit and it will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder for this to work,

you must put this code in a file named update.php

"marquee" must be the name of your table

"scroll" must be the name of your row inside the table

"1" must be the id name for the row "scroll"

**this is the database connection**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

**This is the html form**

```
<?php echo "
<form method=\"POST\" action=\"update.php\">
<br/>Update scroll to: <input type=\"text\" name=\"new_value\" />
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" /> "; ?>
```

this is how php will process the submitted data.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['new_value']) && !empty($_POST['new_value'])) {
$new_value =   mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['new_value']));
mysql_query("UPDATE marquee SET scroll='$new_value' WHERE id='1' ") or die(mysql_error());

} else {echo "Please choose your update term";}

?>
```

Comment: Good, I am glad it did. Now, don't forget to mark this as answered.